# Evaluating the integral $\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{|x|+a}}$

Tags: integration

How to compute the following integral
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{|x|+a}}?$$

with $a>0$. I've been searching for hours in my books to find a pattern, but unfortunately with no success.

Comment: Try the cases $x>0$ and $x<0$ separately, then see if you spot a relation afterwards?

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to calculate the integral in the absence of some limits

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite it as follows:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pm x+a}}$$

Where the sign depends on the sign is equal to the sign of $x$:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pm x+a}}=\int (\pm x+a)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\pm 2(\pm x+a)^{\frac{1}{2}}+c$$

So the answer is:
$$sgn(x) 2(|x|+a)^{\frac{1}{2}}+c$$